# adding attributes to auto generated code

Tags: c#, attributes, partial-classes

I designed a database, generated c# code with sqlmetal, and it all works. 
Now, I'm working on a UI, and I want to add some attributes to the classes created by sqlmetal.
after reading this SO Q&A: [Can I define properties in partial classes, then mark them with attributes in another partial class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3782405/can-i-define-properties-in-partial-classes-then-mark-them-with-attributes-in-an) and this atrticle: [MSDN - MetadataTypeAttribute Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.metadatatypeattribute.aspx) I tried the following:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(GUI.metadata.BooksMetaData))]
public partial class Book
{
    public void fun()
    {
        
    }
}

namespace GUI.metadata
{
    public class BooksMetaData
    {
        [DisplayName("hello")]
        public object Shelf { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I checked if VS reconizes the attributes of `Book` in the function `fun`, and it dosen't, so I'm not suprised that the `DisplayName` attribute made no change.

what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it?

(I'm using c#, VS 2010 pro and the code generated by sqlmetal is in a different .dll than the GUI is in)

Comment: You will save yourself a lot of pain by creating ViewModels in your UI to represent your entities. They will automagically allow the attributes too.

Answer (score 2):

Please note that in the thread you mentioned one of the comments say: "it is not a general solution to the question posed by the OP. Consumers of the attributes still need to know to look for the meta data class -- i.e. these attributes will not be returned by Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(...)."
Which means it's not a generic solution to add attributes. It's a solution which requires that methods which reads attributes understands "MetadataType" a just goes to another class for additional attributes. It does not happen automatically.

I know it's not a full answer, but I would suggest some kind of post-processing with Mono.Cecil, for example:

```
// pseudo code!

// for every type in assembly...
foreach (var targetType in assembly.Types)
{
    // find type which adds attributes to original type
    var sourceTypeName = targetType.Name + "Attributes";
    var sourceType = assembly.Types.FirstOfDefault(t => t.Name = sourceTypeName);

    if (sourceType == null) continue; // no type adding attributes

    // for each property in this type...
    foreach (var targetProperty in targetType.Properties)
    {
        // find property which is supposed to have additional attributes
        var sourceProperty = sourceType.Properties.FirstOfDefault(
            p => p.Name = targetProperty.Name);
        if (sourceProperty == null) continue; // no such property

        // copy attributes
        foreach (var sourceAttribute in sourceProperty.Attributes)
        {
            targetProperty.Attributes.Add(sourceAttribute);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. I don't really like this approach. Is there any other way? I'm not fixed on attributes, I just need a simple way to customize the table.

Answer (score 0):

Other approach is to use interfaces. You can extract the interface from the generated class into another file. Then add the attributes you want to the interface members.

Example:

```
public IGeneratedClassInterface {
     [SomeAtribute("valx")]
     public string field1{get;}
     ...
}

//must be on the same namespace of the generated class
public partial Class GeneratedClassInterface :IGeneratedClassInterface {}
```

Any field you want to hide, just remove from the interface.

Any schema modification will result on a compile error before break your interface.