# Add attribute to method without modifying the code file containing the method?

Tags: c#, attributes, service-reference

Is there a way to add an attribute to a method without modifying the class file?

E.g. I'm importing a WSDL which generates a Reference.cs containing a proxy class with methods.

I have written an attribute which does some work for me and adding it to the method like below, and all works fine:

## Reference.cs file

```
public partial class Whatever
{
    [MyCustomAttrubute()]
    public void MyMethod(string bleh)
    {
        // do stuff
        return;
    }
}
```

However, my problem with this is that if the WSDL changes I will need to update it, which will automatically lose all my changes to Reference.cs. Can I add this attribute to the method from another file?

Comment: In general no... See http://stackoverflow.com/q/3782405/613130 for properties... There is an hack through the `MetadataTypeAttribute` but it is only usable by some classes that know about it.

Comment: I am not sure but it seems that your custom(modified a little) T4 template can help you.

Comment: If you like a world of pain you might try [dynamically generated code and compiling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/650ax5cx(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score -2):

If your other method is also a string, can you not just concatenate the other method to this? In other words when you call MyMethod(string bleh), just pass 2 strings concatenated to it.

For example: 
MyMethod(string1 + "|" + string2);

this would pass 2 parameters concatenated with a pipe, then in the method you can use

string[] vals = val.Split('|');

which would give you an array of the parameters passed. this way you could also pass more than 2 parameters through.

then you could get the parameters as:

sting para1 = vals[0];
sting para2 = vals[1];

Comment: Reference.cs is an auto generated file which is created when you import a WSDL and the attribute is fairly complicated and i need it as an attribute.

Comment: Then serialise it before you pass it as a string and deserialise it back on the other end.

Comment: It is not answer for the question