# Customizing Entity Framework generated classes

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2

So I have a few model classes generated by entity framework and I want to customize at least one to fit my project needs. Here is the generated class:

```
    public partial class Token
    {
        public string token_admin { get; set; }
        public string username { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
    }
```

And here is how I want to customize it:

```
    public partial class Token : IdentityUser
    {
        public string token_admin { get; set; }
        public string username { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public string password { get; set; }
    }
```

Obviously each time the models are generated, the `IdentityUser` and decoration `[JsonIgnore]` disappear, making it hard to be consistent in my web api returns and impossible to find users using the http filter I setup... (the latter is actually a whole different problem on it's own)

I've been searching but can't find a clear answer to what is required to do here. Any suggestions?

FYI, this is part of a school lab so be lenient on the quality of what I do ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3782405/can-i-define-properties-in-partial-classes-then-mark-them-with-attributes-in-an

Comment: What templates are you using?

Comment: I didn't create the EF originally. It's an SQL binding as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

You should not have to modify the Entity models because you should not return Entity models from your WebApi. 
Create a separate Token class in your WebApi project and map it with entity framework's model class.

Comment: sounds feasible but how to 'map' exactly?

Comment: I use AutoMapper(http://automapper.org/) to map models between different layers. This will be helpful https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Getting-started