# Is there any other way of ignoring a property during JSON serialization instead of using [JsonIgnore] decorator?

Tags: c#, data-binding, maui, json-serialization, community-toolkit-mvvm

I am using .net Maui MVVM source generators to create properties as observable properties. I am using System.Text.Json.Serialization to serialize the properties of a class to JSON. When I use [JsonIgnore] on some properties they still get serialized to JSON. Is there any other way of ignoring properties?

I assume that the problem is that I am putting the decorator on the private property declaration and not the public one as the public ones are created in dependencies -> analyzers -> CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.SourceGenerators.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you want that model to serialize? In MVVM you typically bind to the viewmodel and serialize the model.

Comment: Don't think there is another way to ignore. But you could try to set the attribute in a different file: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3782405/can-i-define-properties-in-partial-classes-then-mark-them-with-attributes-in-an

Comment: I can't seem to find the blog post, but propagation of adornments to the generated property will look like `[property: JsonIgnore]`. I don't know if that is in production build yet.

Comment: According to the [official document about the [JsonIgnore] attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/ignore-properties?pivots=dotnet-7-0), it should work. You can try to use `[JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.Always)]`

Comment: PLEASE copy code into question as text, rather than as an image. I had to manually re-type that, to use it in my answer.

Answer (score 5):

I can't seem to find the blog post, but propagation of attribute to the generated property is this syntax: `[property: SomePropertyAttributeHere]`:

```cs
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
...
[ObservableProperty]
[property: JsonIgnore]
RecommendationsType recommendationsList;
```

This generates a property with the attribute attached:

```cs
[JsonIgnore]
RecommendationsType RecommendationsList
{
    get ...
    set ...
}
```

Comment: This feature is production ready and I thought of the same, but this syntax does not allow to specify a target property. So it cannot be used in `AssemblyInfo.cs` for instance, because there is no way to tell the compiler which property is supposed to get the attribute. I think it's only supposed to be used in the "vicinity" of properties (e.g. in `record Foo([property: NotNullWhen(...)] string? Bar, ...);`).

Comment: Right, it is always used with a property Generator. I don't know anything about `AssemblyInfo.cs`, but for this question it goes with `[ObservableProperty]` attribute. It gets transferred to the generated property. Updated answer.

Comment: But this would require OP to change the generated code, because they have to set the attribute on the backing field.

Comment: No, the backing field is what they have in *their* source. It is what is shown in question. The public property is what gets generated. (If their source had the public property, then they would simply put `[JsonIgnore]` on it, and be done.)

Comment: Oh yes, of course. I forgot.

Comment: Works great. Are there any documentations about this?